# SUPEE-5344 and SUPEE-1533 solution for magento ce-1.3?

Tags: security, magento-community, magento-1.3

Reading about those [security risks](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63858/critical-reminder-download-and-install-magento-security-patches-ftp-with-no-s), I wonder if there is something I can do for clients with 1.3 ce stores, where upgrade will require a new theme development.

Comment: I'm guessing that if you client isn't willing to upgrade Magento and stay in a very OLD version (let's face it), then that must mean they're not running a really big business, so why would someone bother trying to exploit these security risks ...?

Comment: @JulienLachal you should also consider automatic bots searching for out-dated systemse across the internet. I think it might come pretty soon with that exploit becoming more popular. It's never good to stay on so out-dated platform without applying proper patches. If theme is the only argument coming from clients I think adapting theme for newer version is not so much of a work to worry about comparing to cleaning up after someone's who exploited the shop.

Comment: Size doesn't matter, exploitability does. Expect automated scans for all versions.

Answer (score 3):

You can find patches for Magento CE **versions 1.5.x and below** for the SUPEE-5344 exploit on this website https://www.nublue.co.uk/blog/magento-remote-code-execution-bug-patches-for-pre-1-6-versions/. It should not be any trouble to patch.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to download these patches for versions 1.6 and up from the official website only: https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/

Comment: 5344 and 1533 patches are also available for 1.4 and 1.5 on the official download page