# Critical security Patches

Tags: magento-community, security, patches

I got this Notification message every time i open the admin.

**Can anybody tell me in detail what to do ?**

**How to install these patches ?**

[image]

Comment: no one really cares that these patches were released 7 and 3 months ago.. lol magento, way to go....

Comment: It's possible more than one patch file will install in Magento ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply refer to the [Magento Community Edition Patches](https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/) on the Magento site.

You can download both `SUPEE-5344` & `SUPEE-1533` there. Choose the relevant download for your version of Magento.

Here's a guide on how to install the patches from the Magento Commerce wiki:

[Magento Tutorial-How to Apply a Patch](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/magento_tutorial_-_how_to_apply_a_patch)

Comment: My website is online on the server How can i get this command line ?

Comment: Use SSH to apply the patches. If you do not have access request it from your host (you'll likely need an IP whitelisting) - alternatively refer to: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63858/critical-reminder-download-and-install-magento-security-patches-ftp-with-no-s

Comment: I've followed this PHP way to Apply The patches 
this patch SUPEE-5344 Applied/reverted successfully 
but the other one  SUPEE-1533 gave me this Message 
http://pastebin.com/Up9jtxam

Comment: i Used 

    <?php
    print("<PRE>");
    passthru("/bin/bash PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh");
    print("</PRE>");
    ?>

Comment: That means you already have the patch, or you have a version that already contains the patch. Make sure to see if the patch is necessary for your Magento version.