# Magento 1.9 CRITICAL security patch

Tags: magento-1.9

when i logged into my magento store admin, it shown a new critical message like Critical error 
Urgent: Immediately install Magento critical security patches

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63858/critical-reminder-download-and-install-magento-security-patches-ftp-with-no-s

Comment: How to install magento security patches

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your website is VULNERABLE to the bug at https://shoplift.byte.nl.

if you are site is not safe then follow the steps.

Magento provides users with patches which may contain fixes for certain issues and/or add new functionality to a particular version of Magento.The reminder sent to all developers and merchants of the store to update this patches (SUPEE-5344 and SUPEE-1533).This 2 patches (SUPEE-5344 and SUPEE-1533) are available at the https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/ . try downloading this two patches from here.

For Installing this 2 patches you need SSH requirment.but some of the hosting providers wont allow the ssh access.

It is still possible to install this 2 patches without the help of the SSH.You can do it with the PHP also.

just download this 2 files from the https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/ .When i downloaded the 2 files names was as follows

1) Patch SUPEE-5344 :- PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh

2) Patch SUPEE-1533 :- PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh

This Both patch is for the Magento 1.9.0.1. you can get patch file for other magento version also you just need to select the magento version and download respective patch files.

Now just upload this 2 files to the magento root directory through the ftp and create a php file called applypatch.php with the following contents

1) for the first patch 5344

```
<?php
print("<PRE>");
passthru("/bin/bash PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh");
print("</PRE>");
?>
```

and run this file through browser http://www.yourdomain.com/applypatch.php

you will see the following output in the browser

Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully…

Patch was applied/reverted successfully.

2) for the second patch 1533

```
<?php
print("<PRE>");
passthru("/bin/bash PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh");
print("</PRE>");
?>
```

and run this file through browser http://www.yourdomain.com/applypatch.php

you will see the following output in the browser

Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully…

Patch was applied/reverted successfully.

Patch has been applied successfully.to check patch has applied or not visit https://shoplift.byte.nl and provide their your domain name and the admin path and Test.

you will see “SAFE – good, http://www.yourdomain.com seems safe! Tweet this happy news”

Now you can see the list of core files which has been updated by this 2 patches in the file called applied.patches.list at app/etc/

Comment: Patch was applied successfully. But  when i logged into my magento store admin, again it is shown a new critical message.

Comment: you need to click on Mark as Read of that message.click on the go to the message then click on the mark as read on the messages.

Comment: have u checked your site in the shoplift.byte.nl. if your site shown as safe here then patch is applied and no need to worry

Comment: It's possible more than one patch file will install in Magento ..?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below link which will guide you in how to apply patches:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html#apply