# How to extract security patch files from sh file

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, supee-7405

I need to install security patch `"PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.2.2_v1-2016-01-20-04-35-33.sh"` in magento ver 1.9.2.2 . Is there any way I can extract package of complete patch files from this file.

Comment: Also see this question about how to patch without SSH access http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/63858/3326

Answer (score 3):

You can not extract Patch files. It doesn't contain files. It contains code to push on each file effected by **SUPEE-7405**.

The following files are effected by SUPEE-7405 v1 patch:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Redirectpolicy.php
app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/User.php
app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Tab/History.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Catalog/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/File.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image/Favicon.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Admin.php
app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Data.php
app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Adminhtml/Authorizenet/Directpost/PaymentController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/etc/config.xml
app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Helper/Minsaleqty.php
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/controllers/CustomerController.php
app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Abstract.php
app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Abstract.php
app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/config.xml
app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/system.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Observer.php
app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Queue.php
app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowadvancedController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/etc/config.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/etc/config.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Block/Catalog/Salesrule.php
app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Helper/Order.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Helper/Guest.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/authorizenet/directpost/iframe.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/create/items/renderer.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/view/items/renderer.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/create/items/renderer.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/view/items/renderer.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/order/view/items/renderer.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/create/items/renderer.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/view/items/renderer.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/composite/fieldset/options/type/file.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/creditmemo/name.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/invoice/name.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/name.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/renderer/default.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/totals/discount.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
lib/Varien/Io/File.php
```

**Source** : https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-7405-without-ssh/

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Patch files are not archives. They do not contain files. You cannot extract files from them.

Patch files are a structured shell script file that uses the *nix utility `patch` to find chunks of code in files, match the original content and then change specific sections in that content to modify the file contents.

If rather, you are asking to know what files will be patched by this patch file, then it's as easy as loading a copy in a programmer's text editor and sorting the file content on the first four characters of each line. All the patched files will show up with `+++` as the first four characters (three pluses and a space). This will be a list of all files that will be modified or added when the patch is executed.

Short sample of the sorted output from SUPEE-7405:

```
+++ lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Redirectpolicy.php
+++ app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/invoice/name.phtml
+++ app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php
+++ app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/name.phtml
+++ app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a .zip of all the files, I've had to use these as I do not have root/ssh access.
http://magentary.com/wph/contentary/uploads/SUPEE-7405-1.9.2.2.zip

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the PATCH from the .sh script as follows, to be used by the patch command:

```
sed -n -e '/^__PATCHFILE/,$p' PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.0_v2-2016-10-14-09-39-55.sh\?raw\=true > PATCH_SUPE5.patchCE_1.9.2.0_v2-2016-10-14-09-39-55
```

Answer (score -1):

Patches don't content any file this is contain some script which is pushed on the correct line at the time of patching.