# Magento 1.7.0.2 - cannot install SUPEE 2629 (PHP 5.4 patch)

Tags: magento-1.7, php-5.4, patches, windows

I have downloaded fresh copy of Magento 1.7.0.2 and PHP 5.4 patch for 1.7.0.2 version, problem is I can't install patch via SSH, working with Magento on local disk! I have found similar problems, other people had HUNK fail problem, my problem is somewhat different, as shown on picture, tried with "sh" and "bash" commands, same problem.

For SSH client, I'm using MobaXterm, not sure if that is relevant. I'm new in coding, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

**UPDATE:** I have installed Cygwin, started the Cygwin shell and tried to execute patch and then it shows

> Error! Some required system tools, that are utilizied in this sh script, are not installed: Tool(s) 'patch' is(are) missed, please install it(them).

I searched on Cygwin page, under Cygwin Package Search, and for 'patch' it finds 2546 matches. What now?

**UPDATE:** It worked, thank you! I have replied today because once everything has been installed (including 9 security patches), forgot to post update, I tried to upvote the answer but it didn't accept, probably because of reputation not being high enough! Anyway, thanks again **fschmengler!**

[image]

Comment: Please also read http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/63858/3326 on how to apply a patch without SSH

Answer (score 0):

It looks like MobaXterm uses some kind of Unix shell emulator (BusyBox) when run on localhost (a **Windows** computer that normally would not have the Unix commands).

The patch scripts use the [`patch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch) Unix command with the `--dry-run` parameter, but the BusyBox implementation does not know this parameter.

For Windows I can recommend [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) instead. You don't need to SSH into localhost with it, just start the Cygwin shell and execute the patch there.

---

> I searched on Cygwin page, under Cygwin Package Search, and for 'patch' it finds 2546 matches. What now?

Install the package `patch-2.7.4-1` with the cygwin installer. I found it by searching "patch.exe"