# Not able to install 3941 patch for Magento 1.8 via PHP script

Tags: magento-1.8, security, patches

I downloaded the SUPEE-3941 patch file from https://magento.com/tech-resources/download, saved it in the Magento root folder and 
created a patch.php file under the root folder.

**patch.php**

```
<?php
 print("<PRE>");
 passthru("/bin/bash PATCH_SUPEE-3941_EE_1.14.0.1_v1-2015-02-10-08-32-02.sh");
 print("</PRE>");
 echo "Done";
?>
```

after hitting the URL mysite/patch.php it shows "done". But when I open the file `app/etc/applied.patches.list`, the patch SUPEE-3941 is not shown as installed.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the output is only "Done", the `passtru` command did not execute successfully.

You can try to find out why by enabling error reporting:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

But I would not recommend installing patches via browser at all. If you have SSH access, run the patch from the console. If not, check out the alternatives posted here: [Critical Reminder: Download and install Magento security patches. (FTP with no SSH access)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63858/critical-reminder-download-and-install-magento-security-patches-ftp-with-no-s)

Comment: Thank you so much @Fabian for your answer. You are right passthru command didn't executing successfully in my case. I just delete that file from server and re upload it . I don't know how but it worked for me.