# SecurityPatch 9652: Possible problems after SUPEE-9652 applied

Tags: magento-1, security, patches, supee-9652

Magento has released its security patch `SUPEE-9652`, for **Magento 1.x CE and EE**

I just want to know **what are the possible problems after applying this security patch
and What are the new changes in this security patch?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's a super tiny patch, here's the diff:

```
diff --git lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php
index b24026b..9323f58 100644
--- lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php
+++ lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php
@@ -119,14 +119,19 @@ class Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail extends Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract
                 );
             }

-            set_error_handler(array($this, '_handleMailErrors'));
-            $result = mail(
-                $this->recipients,
-                $this->_mail->getSubject(),
-                $this->body,
-                $this->header,
-                $this->parameters);
-            restore_error_handler();
+            // Sanitize the From header
+            if (!Zend_Validate::is(str_replace(' ', '', $this->parameters), 'EmailAddress')) {
+                throw new Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception('Potential code injection in From header');
+            } else {
+                set_error_handler(array($this, '_handleMailErrors'));
+                $result = mail(
+                    $this->recipients,
+                    $this->_mail->getSubject(),
+                    $this->body,
+                    $this->header,
+                    $this->parameters);
+                restore_error_handler();
+            }
         }

         if ($this->_errstr !== null || !$result) {
```

However, **Peter O'Callaghan (the one and only) seems to have found a bug. He gently shared the details with me and said I could share it with you here so here it is**:

> Best I can tell the value of `$this->params` will always be prefixed
>   `-f` at the point the validation has been added (it’s passed into the
>   constructor at the point the return path is added). Therefore at the
>   point it’s passed to the validation, if I’ve configured my e-mail
>   `contact@me.com`, the value that’s actually being
>   validated is `-fcontact@me.com`, it seems more of a
>   fluke than an intention that this happens to validate as an e-mail
>   address. If my e-mail address was `"example"@example.com` though, this
>   would become `-f"example"@example.com`, which won’t validate.
>   Incidentally the `str_replace` seems completely redundant in this matter
>   given that AFAIK a space can only be used in conjunction with quotes,
>   and e-mails with quotes won’t validate with the `-f` prefix. In fact
>   if it wasn’t for the prefix being there, the str_replace and validate
>   wouldn’t be useful because `"foo bar"@example.com` and
>   `"foobar"@example.com` both validate, since the latter is never
>   assigned to anything after the replacement, the e-mail would still be
>   sent using the former value, which would presumably still be
>   vulnerable.

Two other things to keep in mind:

- The CE version of the patch also has 'EE_1.14.3.1' listed as the version. It doesn't affect applying, just adds wrong version to `app/etc/applied.patches.list` it feels a bit odd. (source: https://twitter.com/JohnHughes1984/status/829050203139358720)
- As long as you have the email settings disabled (see here: https://magento.com/security/news/new-zend-framework-1-security-vulnerability), there's no hurry with this one BUT **you'll have to do it because any new patch will require this to be installed (as they go on top of each other).**

### Side note

The corresponding new release of Magento CE 1.9.3.2 also includes the copyright comment year update (from 2016 to 2017) so almost every files of Magento has been updated and the diff looks huge

Comment: "As long as you have the email settings disabled" which settings are these in the admin panel mate? Just to save me diving through Sys->Config without having had my coffee :)

Comment: @LukeRodgers refer to this blog post for details: https://magento.com/security/news/new-zend-framework-1-security-vulnerability

Comment: "copyright comment year update (from 2016 to 2017) so almost every files of Magento has been updated" that is truth @Raphael at Digital Pianism

Comment: Does this mean, VERSION 2 of the patch to be released?

Comment: @Icon well if you check the patch file name it's already v2 ^^ so possibly a v3 no ETA yet

Comment: If there is a v3 hopefully they'll spell `applying` correctly on line 2 ;)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism is the problem found by Peter causing any issues or just weird thing.

Comment: @PiotrKaminski I suggest you hit him up directly as I'm not 100% sure. AFAI understand it doesn't seem like a right fix and causes issues in case you have a return configuration setup

Comment: funny. the filename says 9652_v2, but it writes "SUPEE-9652 | EE_1.14.3.1 | v1" to applied.patches.list

Comment: For the record, it's extremely unlikely to affect any legitimate use and AFAIK (without seeing the submitted payload), it would prevent exploitation in all cases (though the actual reason for this seems either unintentional, or an extremely odd choice). It's just that it blocks all e-mails where the local portion is quote encased, i.e.`"example"@example.com` form addresses, regardless of whether they're technically dangerous. I'd be pretty surprised if there are any legit stores using this type of e-mail, but wanted the information available in-case.

Answer (score 8):

Little tip for upgrading; after copying the new version over your existing install, run `git diff -w --stat=400 | grep -v " 2 +”` to quickly see diffs that contain more changes than just the copyright notice change.

Answer (score 4):

The Security Patch 9652 affects only the following file:

```
/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php
```

Answer (score 1):

For those like me who wonder what to do without SSH access: edit file /lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php

from line 122 onwards, replace this:

```
        set_error_handler(array($this, '_handleMailErrors'));
        $result = mail(
            $this->recipients,
            $this->_mail->getSubject(),
            $this->body,
            $this->header,
            $this->parameters);
        restore_error_handler();
```

with this:

```
        // Sanitize the From header
        if (!Zend_Validate::is(str_replace(' ', '', $this->parameters), 'EmailAddress')) {
            throw new Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception('Potential code injection in From header');
        } else {
            set_error_handler(array($this, '_handleMailErrors'));
            $result = mail(
                $this->recipients,
                $this->_mail->getSubject(),
                $this->body,
                $this->header,
                $this->parameters);
            restore_error_handler();
        }
```

Comment: hm, for those without SSH access. maybe you should patch locally and upload the patched file. ;)

Comment: For full guidance on patching without SSH access, see this answer here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/63936/3326