# magento : Security patch 9652

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-9652

I applied Security patch 9652 to my local.Its coming

```
    sh PATCH_SUPEE-9652_v2-2017-02-07-01-18-38.sh
    PATCH_SUPEE-9652_v2-2017-02-07-01-18-38.sh: 14:PATCH_SUPEE9652_v2-2017-02-07-01-18-38.sh: 127: not found
    PATCH_SUPEE-9652_v2-2017-02-07-01-18-38.sh: 14:PATCH_SUPEE9652_v2-2017-02-07-01-18-38.sh: 127: not found
    PATCH_SUPEE-9652_v2-2017-02-07-01-18-38.sh: 25: PATCH_SUPEE9652_v2-2017-02-07-01-18-38.sh: 0: not found
   Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
  -e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
```

Is this patch applied or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check this patch Manually

ust goto `lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php`

```
 diff --git lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php
    index b24026b..9323f58 100644
    --- lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php
    +++ lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php
    @@ -119,14 +119,19 @@ class Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail extends Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract
                     );
                 }

    -            set_error_handler(array($this, '_handleMailErrors'));
    -            $result = mail(
    -                $this->recipients,
    -                $this->_mail->getSubject(),
    -                $this->body,
    -                $this->header,
    -                $this->parameters);
    -            restore_error_handler();
    +            // Sanitize the From header
    +            if (!Zend_Validate::is(str_replace(' ', '', $this->parameters), 'EmailAddress')) {
    +                throw new Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception('Potential code injection in From header');
    +            } else {
    +                set_error_handler(array($this, '_handleMailErrors'));
    +                $result = mail(
    +                    $this->recipients,
    +                    $this->_mail->getSubject(),
    +                    $this->body,
    +                    $this->header,
    +                    $this->parameters);
    +                restore_error_handler();
    +            }
             }

             if ($this->_errstr !== null || !$resul
```

Comment: yes that file changed with that code @Amit

Comment: That means patches has been applied

Comment: how to verify pathes applied or not in local

Comment: there are no verify cation process available for this patch http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/159970/4564

Comment: what type of problems will face after applying 9652 patch

Comment: Fellow http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158666/securitypatch-9652-possible-problems-after-supee-9652-applied