# Email sending stopped after installing SUPEE 8788, 9767, 9652

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-8788, supee-9767, supee-9652

Recently i install some SUPEE as described above,
After installing those magento can't able to send email to customers.
But server sending normal mail with simple PHP mail.

Anyone facing same issue ??
Please help me out.
My magento version is 1.9.2.4 CE.

Answer (score 0):

I think Issue is not with the `SUPEE-9767` or `SUPEE-8788` , Because this 2 does not any content related to Email ,

but yes you may have some issue with `SUPEE-9652` which contains some code for email.

First Revert `SUPEE-9652` patch for revert patch follow this tutorial

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html#revert

and check if your email is working then check this my post for your issue that may help you

[SecurityPatch 9652: Possible problems after SUPEE-9652 applied](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158666/securitypatch-9652-possible-problems-after-supee-9652-applied)